# Reducing the number of code lines when declaring Image or text views

Tags: java, android

Is there a way do use less code lines to declare multiple image/Text Views in AndroidStudio? Currently I have this initialization, but it's only a quarter of the total I need. As you can see I am using the same image 3 times, placed in different cardViews. The only issue I have with this is that the code gets huge, I have no issue reading it, but I would like to make it more "professional".

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ArduinoListener {
    private Arduino arduino;


    //Declaring the volume layout and the volume text box
    private TextView volume;


    //Declaring the Radio Layout and the textviews
    private LinearLayout radio3x4grid;
    private TextView radio1x2text;
    private TextView radio1x3text;
    private TextView radio1x4text;
    //----------------------------
    CardView radio2x1card;
    private TextView radio2x1text;
    CardView radio2x2card;
    private TextView radio2x2text;
    CardView radio2x3card;
    private TextView radio2x3text;
    CardView radio2x4card;
    private TextView radio2x4text;
    //----------------------------
    private TextView radio3x2text;
    private TextView radio3x3text;
    private TextView radio3x4text;


    //Declaring the 3x2 menu Layout
    private LinearLayout complex3x2grid;
    private TextView complex1x2text;
    private TextView complex2x2text;
    private TextView complex3x2text;
    //-----------------------------
    private ImageView iconAudioSettings1x1;
    private ImageView iconAudioSettings2x1;
    private ImageView iconAudioSettings3x1;
    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    private ImageView iconPhoneSettings1x1;
    private ImageView iconPhoneSettings2x1;
    private ImageView iconPhoneSettings3x1;
    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    private ImageView iconSystemSettings1x1;
    private ImageView iconSystemSettings2x1;
    private ImageView iconSystemSettings3x1;
    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    private ImageView iconBluetooth1x1;
    private ImageView iconBluetooth2x1;
    private ImageView iconBluetooth3x1;
    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    private ImageView iconMusicNote1x1;
    private ImageView iconMusicNote2x1;
    private ImageView iconMusicNote3x1;
    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    private ImageView iconUSB1x1;
    private ImageView iconUSB2x1;
    private ImageView iconUSB3x1;
    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    private ImageView iconVolume1x1;
    private ImageView iconVolume2x1;
    private ImageView iconVolume3x1;
    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    private ImageView iconRingtone1x1;
    private ImageView iconRingtone2x1;
    private ImageView iconRingtone3x1;
    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    private ImageView iconCercle1x1empty;
    private ImageView iconCercle2x1empty;
    private ImageView iconCercle3x1empty;
    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    private ImageView iconCercle1x1full;
    private ImageView iconCercle2x1full;
    private ImageView iconCercle3x1full;



    //Declaring the volume settings Layout
    private LinearLayout settigsMenuProgressBar;
    private ProgressBar menuVolumeProgressBar;
    private TextView functionName;
    private TextView currentValue;


    //Declaring the musical atmosphere menu Layout
    private LinearLayout musicalAtmosphere;
    private ImageView emptyCercleRow1;
    private ImageView checkedCercleRow1;
    private ImageView emptyCercleRow2;
    private ImageView checkedCercleRow2;
    private ImageView emptyCercleRow3;
    private ImageView checkedCercleRow3;
    private TextView musicalAtmosphereMainText1;
    private TextView musicalAtmosphereMainText2;
    private TextView musicalAtmosphereMainText3;
    CardView cardRow2;
    CardView cardText2;
    private LinearLayout bassTrebleLayout;
    CardView bassTextCard;
    CardView trebleTextCard;
    private ProgressBar bassProgressBar;
    private ProgressBar trebleProgressBar;


    //Declaring the Source Tab Layout
    CardView radioCard;
    CardView cdplayerCard;
    CardView auxCard;

    String messageReceived = "";
    int a = 0;
    int menuVolumeCounter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        arduino = new Arduino(this, 250000);


        volume = findViewById(R.id.volume_text);

        //Declaring radio 3x4 grid and it's cards and text views
        radio3x4grid = findViewById(R.id.radio3x4grid);
        //--------------------------------------------
        radio1x2text = findViewById(R.id.radio1x2text);
        radio1x3text = findViewById(R.id.radio1x3text);
        radio1x4text = findViewById(R.id.radio1x4text);
        //--------------------------------------------
        radio2x1card = findViewById(R.id.radio2x1card);
        radio2x1text = findViewById(R.id.radio2x1text);
        radio2x2card = findViewById(R.id.radio2x2card);
        radio2x2text = findViewById(R.id.radio2x2text);
        radio2x3card = findViewById(R.id.radio2x3card);
        radio2x3text = findViewById(R.id.radio2x3text);
        radio2x4card = findViewById(R.id.radio2x4card);
        radio2x4text = findViewById(R.id.radio2x4text);
        //--------------------------------------------
        radio3x2text = findViewById(R.id.radio3x2text);
        radio3x3text = findViewById(R.id.radio3x3text);
        radio3x4text = findViewById(R.id.radio3x4text);


        //Declaring 3x2 grid with the first column for icons and second column for text
        complex3x2grid = findViewById(R.id.complex3x2grid);
        complex1x2text = findViewById(R.id.complex1x2text);
        complex2x2text = findViewById(R.id.complex2x2text);
        complex3x2text = findViewById(R.id.complex3x2text);
        //------------------------------------------------
        iconAudioSettings1x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex1x1audioSettings);
        iconAudioSettings2x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex2x1audioSettings);
        iconAudioSettings3x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex3x1audioSettings);
        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        iconPhoneSettings1x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex1x1phoneSettings);
        iconPhoneSettings2x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex2x1phoneSettings);
        iconPhoneSettings3x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex3x1phoneSettings);
        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        iconSystemSettings1x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex1x1systemSettings);
        iconSystemSettings2x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex2x1systemSettings);
        iconSystemSettings3x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex3x1systemSettings);
        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        iconBluetooth1x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex1x1bluetooth);
        iconBluetooth2x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex2x1bluetooth);
        iconBluetooth3x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex3x1bluetooth);
        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        iconMusicNote1x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex1x1musicNote);
        iconMusicNote2x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex2x1musicNote);
        iconMusicNote3x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex3x1musicNote);
        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        iconUSB1x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex1x1usb);
        iconUSB2x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex2x1usb);
        iconUSB3x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex3x1usb);
        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        iconVolume1x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex1x1volume);
        iconVolume2x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex2x1volume);
        iconVolume3x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex3x1volume);
        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        iconRingtone1x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex1x1ringtone);
        iconRingtone1x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex2x1ringtone);
        iconRingtone1x1 = findViewById(R.id.complex3x1ringtone);
        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        iconCercle1x1empty = findViewById(R.id.complex1x1emptyCircle);
        iconCercle2x1empty = findViewById(R.id.complex2x1emptyCircle);
        iconCercle3x1empty = findViewById(R.id.complex3x1emptyCircle);
        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        iconCercle1x1full = findViewById(R.id.complex1x1fullCircle);
        iconCercle2x1full = findViewById(R.id.complex2x1fullCircle);
        iconCercle3x1full = findViewById(R.id.complex3x1fullcircle);
        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++



        //Declaring the menu Volume progress bar
        settigsMenuProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.settingMenuProgressBarr);
        menuVolumeProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.menuVolumeProgressBar);
        functionName = findViewById(R.id.functionName);
        currentValue = findViewById(R.id.currentValue);


        //Declaring the muscial atmosphere grid with two progress bars
        musicalAtmosphere = findViewById(R.id.musicalAtmosphere);
        emptyCercleRow1 = findViewById(R.id.musicAtRow1EmptyCerc);
        checkedCercleRow1 = findViewById(R.id.musicAtRow1FullCerc);
        emptyCercleRow2 = findViewById(R.id.musicAtRow2EmptyCerc);
        checkedCercleRow2 = findViewById(R.id.musicAtRow2FullCerc);
        emptyCercleRow3 = findViewById(R.id.musicAtRow3EmptyCerc);
        checkedCercleRow3 = findViewById(R.id.musicAtRow3FullCerc);
        //--------------------------------------------------------
        musicalAtmosphereMainText1 = findViewById(R.id.musicalAtmosphereMainText1);
        musicalAtmosphereMainText2 = findViewById(R.id.musicalAtmosphereMainText2);
        musicalAtmosphereMainText3 = findViewById(R.id.musicalAtmosphereMainText3);
        cardRow2 = findViewById(R.id.cardRow2);
        cardText2 = findViewById(R.id.cardText2);
        bassTrebleLayout = findViewById(R.id.bassTrebleLayout);
        bassTextCard = findViewById(R.id.bassTextCard);
        trebleTextCard = findViewById(R.id.trebleTextCard);
        bassProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.bassProgressBar);
        trebleProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.trebleProgressBar);


        //Declaring the source tab with the three card options
        radioCard = findViewById(R.id.sourceRadioCard);
        cdplayerCard = findViewById(R.id.sourceCdplayerCard);
        auxCard = findViewById(R.id.sourceAuxCard);
    }
```

Comment: Where are these coming from? Are you going to be creating them programmatically or are they going to be from an inflated XML file? Seems like this could be avoided sooner than just the variable declarations.

Comment: they are created programmatically. I don't have any experience working with inflated layout.

Comment: In a loop of some sort? If not then maybe they should be? Then they can be put in an array.

Comment: But also there are already some built-in grid layouts for you, so you don't need to nest linear layouts. So you might want to look into using one of those.

Comment: I've attached the main activity an onCreate method, for a better understanding

Comment: Ah, they're not created programmatically here, but they're inflated from `R.layout.activity_main`. Without seeing it I can't say for sure but this seems like a job for a grid-type layout. I can imagine that XML file has a lot of repetition, so that would be the root cause.

Comment: Use Databindings or ViewBinding. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding

Comment: Share a screenshot as well.

Comment: Use **arrays** instead of cloned components 1, 2, 3. Sometimes a table view or such will do too.

Answer (score 0):

If the aim is to reduce the lines of code, than you can define multiple variables (considering they are of same type) in one line like:

```
private TextView radio1x2text, radio1x3text, radio1x4text;
```

Another thing could be handy for you is to use view binding. It will reduce the lines of code when initializing these variables. You can find more details about View binding [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/use-view-binding-to-replace-findviewbyid-c83942471fc).

Comment: I don't think this reflects the real problem with the OPs code, which is that they should be using a grid-style layout for this instead of making it manually.

Comment: Actually that helps, defining multiple variables on the same line code.

Comment: Well it does simplify what you have, but doesn't address the big issue of *why you have it in the first place*.

Comment: Also, I'm not using a grid layout, but I am using a combination of horizontal and vertical lynear layouts, in order to set specific dimensions for my text boxes